# Split csv file using Automator Service (Finder Context Menu)

Tags: bash, macos, automator

I am trying to create an Automator ***Service*** for **Finder**'s Right-Click Context Menu that can split any selected csv file, whilst copying in the original header at the top of every file.

My current attempt is to make Automator run [this Bash Shell Script](https://superuser.com/a/188898/455679):

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=$(ls -1 | grep MY_CSV_FILE.csv)
NAME=${FILE%%.csv}

head -1 $FILE > header.csv
tail -n +2 $FILE > data.csv

split -l 50 data.csv

for a in x??
    do
        cat header.csv $a > $NAME.$a.csv
    done

rm header.csv data.csv x??
```

This script will split `MY_CSV_FILE.csv` into new files with max 50 lines while copying in the original header at the top of every file. The new files will have the original name appended with `xaa`, `xab`, `xac` etc.

Regarding the Automator setup, this is the Service I'm currently working on. The problem right now is that I'm unable to pass the Selected File in Finder to the Bash script.

[image]

Notice that:

- Service receives: *files or folders* in *Finder.app*.
- Pass input to Shell script: *as arguments*.
- I have removed `#!/bin/bash` from the top of the Shell Script and set the Shell to: */bin/bash*.
- I switched `MY_CSV_FILE.csv` for `"$f"` – not sure if that's correct.

Do I also need to specify the path using something like `"$@"` for both the input file and the resulting output files? I haven't done something like this before, so I'm not really familiar with that variable and `"$f"` for that matter.

How could I make this work? I'd like the resulting files to appear in the same folder as the file I select to run the Service on, via the Finder Right-Click Menu. It would be even better if the Service only accepted csv files.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit your script to satisfy the needs

```
set -e

for FILE in "$@"
do
        #must be a file size bigger than zero with extension csv
        if test -f ${FILE}  && test -s ${FILE} &&  test ${FILE: -4} == ".csv" ; then
                NAME=${FILE%%.csv}


                head -1 ${FILE} > header.csv
                tail -n +2 ${FILE} > data.csv

                split -l 50 data.csv

                for a in x??
                do
                        cat header.csv ${a} > ${NAME}.${a}.csv
                done

                rm header.csv data.csv x??

        fi
done
```

Note the origin script  is not so safe, if you have such files in your directory `header.csv` `data.csv` or any file that matches glob pattern `x??`. All these files will be deleted when `rm header.csv data.csv x??` executed.

Answer (score 0):

Use $1, $2, $3, etc. to access the arguments passed into the script. If you want to refer to all of the arguments as an array, use $@.